# How do you associate metadata or annotations to a python function or method?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am looking to build fairly detailed annotations for methods in a Python class. These to be used in troubleshooting, documentation, tooltips for a user interphase, etc. However it's not clear how I can keep these annotations associated to the functions.

For context, this is a feature engineering class, so two example methods might be:

```
def create_feature_momentum(self):
    return self.data['mass'] * self.data['velocity'] * 

def create_feature_kinetic_energy(self):
    return 0.5* self.data['mass'] * self.data['velocity'].pow(2)
```

For example:

1. It'd be good to tell easily what core features were used in each engineered feature.
2. It'd be good to track arbitrary metadata about each method
3. It'd be good to embed non-string data as metadata about each function. Eg. some example calculations on sample dataframes.

So far I've been manually creating docstrings like:

```
def create_feature_kinetic_energy(self)->pd.Series:
    '''Calculate the non-relativistic kinetic energy.

    Depends on: ['mass', 'velocity']
    Supports NaN Values: False
    Unit: Energy (J)

    Example: 
        self.data= pd.DataFrame({'mass':[0,1,2], 'velocity':[0,1,2]})
        self.create_feature_kinetic_energy()
        >>> pd.Series([0, 0.5, 4])

    '''
    return 0.5* self.data['mass'] * self.data['velocity'].pow(2)
```

And then I'm using regex to get the data about a function by inspecting the `__doc__` attribute. However, is there a better place than `__doc__` where I could store information about a function? In the example above, it's fairly easy to parse the `Depends on` list, but in my use case it'd be good to also embed some example data as dataframes somehow (and I think writing them as markdown in the docstring would be hard).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm looking for something very similar. In my project I want to keep track of some associated metadata related to a method/function that generates a feature column.

In the simplest case, I want to at least keep track of what column names this feature function produces on an input pandas dataframe. The doc method here is very interesting, what I've been using is a hardcoded table that I have to maintain in a separate file. Having this metadata directly in the code definition however is better, like your doc method is doing. LMK if you found a better answer!

Comment: I added an answer in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing an class as follows:

```
class ScubaDiver(pd.DataFrame):
    accessed = None

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if self.accessed is None:
            self.accessed = set()
        self.accessed.add(key)
        return pd.Series(dtype=float)

    @property
    def columns(self):
        return list(self.accessed)
```

The way my code is writen, I can do this:

```
sd = ScubbaDiver()

foo(sd)

sd.columns
```

and `sd.columns` contains all the columns accessed by `foo`

Though this might not work in your codebase.

I also wrote this decorator:

```
def add_note(notes: dict):
    '''Adds k:v pairs to a .notes attribute.'''
    def _(f):
        if not hasattr(f, 'notes'):
            f.notes = {}
        f.notes |= notes  # Summation for dicts
        return f
    return _
```

You can use it as follows:

```
@add_note({'Units':'J', 'Relativity':False})
def create_feature_kinetic_energy(self):
    return 0.5* self.data['mass'] * self.data['velocity'].pow(2)
```

and then you can do:

```
create_feature_kinetic_energy.notes['Units']  # J
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer. This is exactly along the lines of what I have explored for doing this, either a class to provide the additional metadata as local state, or a decorator to wrap the function and provide additional context.

The nuance in your case is that ultimately even in the wrapper method you have a reference to `self`where you can store local state. In my case the functions are not methods of any class, and at the moment I guess the __doc__ variable is the best place to put user/dev notes, but the data structure for what you store there is not standardized.

Comment: Oh, fun fact - all functions in Python are objects. That means you can set any attrinute you want and Python will not complain. For example, try this: `myFunction = lambda x: x+9 ; myFunction.author = "Mike" ; assert myFunction.author == "Mike"`